# My Search Icon Disappears after Transition

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I added a search icon with font awesome on my website that has a transition to the left but for some reason when I hover and the transition starts the font awesome icon disappears.
I'm having a hard time figuring this out because it works fine on my CodePen.

Please click on the link below to see the code in action on my website.

[image: Before Hover]

[image: After Hover]

http://lonestarwebandgraphics.com/

Comment: please provide code so we can look for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Adding a link to a live website does not fulfill the requirement for a question to have a [mre] as that live website is presumably going to be fixed and then there will be no record of what the question was referencing making it useless to future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the changes you can add to make it work, I add `position: absolute` along with left, top attributes, and for the search-box container added `min-width` to prevent the container from collapsing since there is no default with for the content inside:

```
#mybottomnav .items .item .search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  background: #2f3640;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#mybottomnav .items .item .search-box .search-btn {
  position: absolute;
  color: lightblue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2f3640;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

**NOTE**: remove this CSS `#mybottomnav .items .item .search-box:hover > .search-btn`

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding **display: flex;** to search-box.

I inspected your website in firefox and added display: flex; to search-box and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
.search-box{
    display: inline-flex;
}
.search-btn{
    background: #2f3640;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

Add following CSS

```
 .#mybottomnav .items .item .search-box {
      min-width: 52px;
  }

  .#mybottomnav .items .item .search-box .search-btn {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      /*float: right;*/ //remove this css
  }
```